# Minimise search time for text in a large CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, csv, search

I have a CSV file with about 700 or so rows and 8 columns, the last column however, has a very big block of text (with enough for multiple long paragraphs inside each).

I'd like to implement through python a text-search function that gives me back all the lines that have text that matches from inside the data from the 8th column (meaning it'd need to go through the whole thing).

What could possibly be the quickest way to approach this and minimise search-time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could dump your csv file into an [sqlite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) database and use sqlite's [full text search](https://sqlite.org/fts5.html) capabilities to do the search for you.

This example code shows how it could be done.  There are a few things to be aware of:

- it assumes that the csv file has a header row.  If this isn't the case, you'll need to provide column names (or just use generic names like "col1", "col2" etc).
- it searches *all* columns in the csv; if that's undesirable, filter out the other columns (and header values) before creating the SQL statements.
- If you want to be able to match the results to rows in the csv file, you'll need create a column that contains the line number.

```py
import csv                                                                                                                                      
import sqlite3                                                                                                                                  
import sys                                                                                                                                      


def create_table(conn, cols, name='mytable'):                                                                                                   
    stmt = f"""CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE "{name}" USING fts5({cols})"""                                                                              
    with conn:                                                                                                                                  
        conn.execute(stmt)                                                                                                                      
    return                                                                                                                                      


def populate_table(conn, reader, cols, ncols, name='mytable'):                                                                                  
    placeholders = ', '.join(['?'] * ncols)                                                                                                     
    stmt = f"""INSERT INTO "{name}" ({cols})                                                                                                    
    VALUES ({placeholders})
    """
    # Filter out any blank rows in the csv
    reader = filter(None, reader)
    with conn:
        conn.executemany(stmt, reader)
    return


def search(conn, term, cols, name='mytable'):
    stmt = f"""SELECT {cols}
    FROM "{name}"
    WHERE "{name}" MATCH ?
    """
    with conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(stmt, (term,))
        result = cursor.fetchall()
    return result


def main(path, term):
    result = 'NO RESULT SET'
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
        with open(path, 'r') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            # Assume headers are in the first row
            headers = next(reader)
            ncols = len(headers)
            cols = ', '.join([f'"{x.strip()}"' for x in headers])
            create_table(conn, cols)
            populate_table(conn, reader, cols, ncols)
        result = search(conn, term, cols)
    finally:
        conn.close()
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(main(*sys.argv[1:]))
```