# Search for a word/phrase in csv file in Python

Tags: python, csv, twitter

I have a database of tweets in csv format which looks like this - [screen of csv database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuiQp.jpg) - and I need to perform the following task with this file using Python code:

Search for certain words/phrases in tweets (text of a tweet is in the column C) and if the tweet has this word/phrase I'm looking for, I need to write the whole row with this tweet to a new csv file

and (if possible) to delete this tweet from the old csv file or create a new one without it.

I hope I made it clear.

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide the code of your attempt at this.

Comment: Related, if your csv is large https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59035613/minimise-search-time-for-python-in-a-large-csv-file/59038701#59038701

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the csv library to read the file and do your search on each row one at a time.

```
import csv

with open('out.csv', 'w', newline='') as output_file:
    writer = csv.writer(output_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    with open('test.csv') as csv_file:
        csv_read = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        for row in csv_read:
            if "a" in row[2]:
                writer.writerow(row)
```

Here is a link to the python docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html. Hope this helps.

EDIT: If you want more than one search term, use any() on a list comprehension.

```
import csv

with open('out.csv', 'w', newline='') as output_file:
    writer = csv.writer(output_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    with open('input.csv') as csv_file:
        csv_read = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        for row in csv_read:
            search_terms = ["term1", "term2"]

            if any([term in row[2] for term in search_terms]):
                writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Actually, this writes only one row in the output file and that's all. There's a for loop, so should be fine, but I don't know why it's like that. I used writerow in the end. That could be the reason?

Comment: @Tomito This change works for me. All I did was use csv's writerow here.

Comment: works, thanks! I just removed delimiter and quotechar stuff, because with them the output file was too messy.

Comment: Another small question, if I may... Is there any way to search for multiple words?
    if ("a", "b") in row[2]: ...
Doesn't really work.

Comment: @Tomito You can use any() to do that. I made an edit that does it. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any

Comment: Thanks so much, you're great!