# Searching large CSV with .txt file keywords

Tags: python, csv

Looking for a solution to the following:

I have 1 large CSV (data.csv) file that contains:

`first name | last name | phone number | email address` etc

I then have a .txt file with a list of names. Text file would be formatted line by line

```
smith
johnson
jones
```

I am looking to search the large CSV, and export every full line with that contains that keyword to another CSV (Results.csv)

Example:

in Data.csv Searching "Smith, Johnson, Jones" (from keyword.txt) would export the full row (if last name matches) to results.csv.

```
John Smith, 1234 Main St, 1800-800-8800, etc
John Johnson, 4321 South St...
```

etc

Searching here, i put together a portion of what i am looking for but still need to figure out how to match the entire row based off a keyword then export it to CSV

```
import re

searchlist = []
with open("keyword.txt") as g:
    for line in g:
        searchlist.append(line.strip())

pattern = re.compile("|".join(searchlist))
with open("data.csv") as f:
    for line in f:
```

Comment: How is the data inside of file.txt ?

Comment: Could a field in your CSV contain multiline text?

Comment: Your sample data doesn't match your description - is first and last name comma separated, or do you need to text search over the full name? You have a strong start! Inside your `for` you should test the line, then store it in a datastructure until you've gone through the whole thing.

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar The text file would be one word per line.

Comment: @aventurin each cell is single line text.

Comment: @mgrollins - Sorry about that. basically, if it finds a key word, i just want it to display that entire row.

Comment: Possibly useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/59038701/5320906

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a specific need for regular expressions, you can do so with:

```
searchlist = []
with open("keyword.txt") as g:
    for line in g:
        searchlist.append(line.strip())

with open("data.csv") as f:
    for line in f:
        if any(s in line for s in searchlist):
            print(line, end='')
```

case insensitive find:

```
        if any(s.upper() in line.upper() for s in searchlist):
            print(line, end='')
```

you can save a few extra cpu cycles by filling searchlist with upper() keywords as you fill it to begin with.

Comment: Okay cool. That seems to show the results. How would i export the rows found to CSV now?