# Partial matching of text in CSV file only using CSV module in python

Tags: python, csv

PROD_ID,MODEL,STATUS,OWNERSHIP
201802,Honda,Average,DeakUIN
202002,Ertiga,Good,NorkU-IT
201702,Gips,Bad,DirkUNI
201703,Honda,Good,NorkU-IT
201704,Honda,Good,Nor-k
201705,Honda,Good,RibssT

Ohh I see, I will elaborate my question.

For the above table we have a unique "Prod ID" column.
So i have to apply filter in csv file where Model == Honda and Ownership column contains "*IT" OR "*rk*" and status should be =="Good" and once all the filter is applied the answer should only show the prod ID

PROD_ID
201703
201704

Comment: Please show a few rows of the input data.

Comment: Somewhat similar https://stackoverflow.com/a/59038701/5320906

Comment: PROD_ID,MODEL,STATUS,OWNERSHIP
201802,Honda,Average,DeakUIN
202002,Ertiga,Good,NorkUIT
201702,Gips,Bad,DirkUNI

Comment: Just so you know, the `re.search(...` doesn't have a closing parenthesis `)`, is that the issue? Also, is this essentially what you're after: Search each row of the table, and if the condition meets (in this case "Honda", "Good", etc) it will print the `PROD_ID`?

Comment: yes that's right.Like i have this CSV file i have to apply multiple filters in multiple columns and sometimes it has multiple conidtions in same column (example - one - could have both values "rk" or "IT") based on all the condition it should bring only the PROD ID values no other column.
I have re-described my question please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are looking for considering the regex expression.
You may want to use *all()* that eliminates the *and* expressions within your IF-Statement. With *in* you search for partial or full matches within strings.

```python
import csv

with open("Report.csv", 'r') as file:
    csv_file = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in csv_file:
        if all([row['MODEL'] == 'Honda', row['STATUS'] == 'Good', "ork" in row['OWNERSHIP']]):
            print(row)
```

The code prints the line given the input:

```
PROD_ID,MODEL,STATUS,OWNERSHIP
201802,Honda,Average,DeakUIN
202002,Ertiga,Good,NorkUIT
201702,Gips,Bad,DirkUNI
201702,Honda,Good,NorkUIT
```

If it is not what you want please re-define revise your question so that we know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Ohh I see, I will elaborate my question.

Comment: PROD_ID MODEL STATUS OWNERSHIP
201802 Honda Average DeakUIN
202002 Ertiga Good NorkU-IT
201702 Gips Bad DirkUNI
201703 Honda Good NorkU-IT
201704 Honda Good Nor-k
201705 Honda Good RibssT


Ohh I see, I will elaborate my question. 

For the above table we have a unique "Prod ID" column.
So i have to apply filter in csv file where Model == Honda and Ownership column contains "*IT" OR "*rk*" and status should be =="Good" and once all the filter is applied the answer should only show the prod ID

PROD_ID
201703
201704